# Android Passing Countdown Timer for 2 Activities or more

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I'm trying to pass the countdownTimer value from the activity 1 to the activity 2 and start the countdown Timer in the activity 2 from the value that got from the activity 1 , But I didn't know how to make the starting point for the timer in the activity 2 as a variable, here is my code for activity 1

```
    new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }
        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("done!");
        }
     }.start();

    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page2.class);
            i.putExtra("timervalue", tv.getText());
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
```

and here is the code in activity 2

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();  
    long value = Long.parseLong(bundle.getString("timervalue"));
    new CountDownTimer(value, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("done!");
        }
     }.start();
```

I also tried to make activity 2 like this by using Intet instead of Bundle

```
    Intent results = this.getIntent();
    String s = results.getExtras().getString("timervalue");
    long value = Long.parseLong(s);

    new CountDownTimer(value, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("done!");
        }
     }.start();
```

I think the error I have when I putExtra and getExtra But I'm not sure ,I'm really beginner in java. So please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here is that you're putting a `String` in extras in `Activity1`, and then trying to fetch a `Long` from the `Bundle` on the other end. Passing value as a `String` is fine, but then you need to parse it as `Long` in `Activity2`. So the code should look like this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();  
    long value = Long.parseLong(bundle.getString("timervalue"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I apply this code the app forced closed don't know why??

Comment: @UsamaAlkhalidy, Take a look at the logcat and tell me what the exception is.

Answer (score 0):

Your extra timervalue is a string ("seconds remaining: " + the seconds remaining). You can not cast this string to a long. You could try something like:

```
String timeValueStr = tv.getText().toString().replace("seconds remaining: ", "");
long value = Long.parseLong(timeValueStr);
```

Comment: When I apply this code the app forced closed don't know why??